# Infinite loop - what is happening?

Tags: c

I have the following code in C which is supposed to return a 4-bit binary representation of every number in a 8-digit long string of numbers. For some reason it's looping infinitely now.

The current output looks like this (with `12345677` as input): `0001 0010 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ...` (endless zeroes). As you can see the first 3 numbers work (which I think is very odd).

What is going wrong here?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    #define LENGTH 8

    int main()
    {
        char number[LENGTH];

        printf("Geef nummers in : ");
        scanf("%s", number);   

        printf("Resultaat : ");

        for(int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++) {

          char re[4];

          re[3] = ((number[i]) & 1) ? '1' : '0';
          number[i] >>= 1;
          re[2] = ((number[i]) & 1) ? '1' : '0';
          number[i] >>= 1;
          re[1] = ((number[i]) & 1) ? '1' : '0';
          number[i] >>= 1;
          re[0] = ((number[i]) & 1) ? '1' : '0';
          number[i] >>= 1;
          re[4] = '\0';

          int res = atoi(re);
          printf("%04d ", res);

        }  

        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: `re[4] = '\0';` undefined behavior at runtime in your code

Comment: Removing that line solved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: your welcome Melvin :)

Comment: Maybe your compiler doesn't like Dutch :-) Just joking, Jim has the answer.

Comment: This is low hanging fruit. A simple loop that should execute a few times continues on -- obviously the limit or the loop variable is being stomped on (in this case most likely `i` is repeatedly being reset to 0). The first thing to look for is array overruns ... number? No, i runs from 0 to LENGTH-1 and isn't changed inside the loop. re? Yes, it jumps right out ... never ever use the size of an array as its index in a 0-indexed language like C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only declare 4 elements for `re` (`0` through `3` inclusive) but you use a 5th element when doing `re[4]`. You are invoking undefined behavior at that point. You need to define `re` as:

```
char re[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing over the bounds of array `re`, by assigning value to `re[4]`.

As *Jim Buck* said, use `char re[5]`, or use index `3` as the last one for array `re`.

Comment: Since you've clearly already seen Jim Buck's answer at the time you posted this, this would have been better as a comment.

Comment: @Vicky : Ya you are right, actually he beat me in posting answer by few seconds, So I just added his name for reference.